# Deciding primary key for DynamoDB

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have 3 fields to store in DynamoDB: identity-1, identity-2, score.
identity-1 and identity-2 are always unique in the table, i.e. no two entries can have same identity-1 or identity-2.

We want to allow entries to either have one of identity-1 or identity-2 or have both. Example:

| identity-1 | identity-2 | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | s1 |
| a2 |  | s2 |
|  | b3 | s3 |

Access patterns are as follows:

1. Query identity-2 from identity-1
2. Query score from identity-1
3. Query score from identity-2

How do I define primary key in such case?

Comment: You need at least one non-optional field to query by. If identity-1 and identity-2 can be empty, you're in trouble ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a "many:1" problem and there's a few ways to tackle it with DynamoDB. The simple answer here is to leverage [Global Secondary Indexes (GSI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html). For every "identity" you wanted to do a direct look up from, you'd create a GSI.

GSI-1 would include Identity-1 as the hash key and you'd include Identity-2 and any other identities as a non-key attribute to include. You'd create a GSI for each identity you wanted to query directly on. You could also include the score as a non-key attribute if you wanted to directly look up score from any identity without having to resolve to the primary key (which we'll talk about).

The thing to consider with GSI's, though, is that they consume extra storage and throughput. If you create a GSI which includes all your attributes for every identity, you'd be paying for an additional copy of your table for each identity.

The other issue, so far, is that you haven't chosen a Primary Key for your table. You'll need a field to be your primary key and if none of your identities is non-nullable, you'll need a field which will be. It's often convenient to just call it what it is, so we'll call it `pk`.

You've got a few choices for `pk` here. Once is to define `pk` as a composite of your identities. For example: `item.pk = item["identity-1"] || item["identity-2"]`. Then you could do a query on the table for the identity == pk and if you don't find anything, you could then look up the index for the given identity. This works fine for your simple example, but as you wanted to do more complex things (such as many different identity types), you might find it to be a bit of a headache.

From past experience, my recommendation would be to adjust your approach slightly, however, and have an "users" table and a "scores" table. "users" would have a pk of a guid unique for every user and all their identities (call it "user_id"), you could then create a GSI for that table for every identity back to user_id. Then scores would then use "user_id" as the pk as well with no need for an index. Your application would always resolve to a "user_id" when a user was logged in or otherwise identified - then you can search for score without needing to track identity and you can look up all the associated identities or other user information without needing to create a very "fat" index of every identity->every other identity.